# Error while cross-compiling rospkg for arm

Tags: cross-compiling

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,I want to cross compile rospackage for arm.I do following the website http://answers.ros.org/question/191070/compile-roscore-for-arm-board/  .   I have created rostoolchain.cmake file like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-g++)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain/lib /home/znzx/boost/lib /opt/ros/hydro/lib)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH  /home/znzx/boost/include /opt/ros/hydro/include /usr/include) 
set(BOOST_LIBRARY  /home/znzx/boost/lib)
set(BOOST_INCLUDE  /home/znzx/boost/include)
set(BOOST_ROOT /home/znzx/boost)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
When I excute `$./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/znzx/catkin_ws/src/rostoolchain.cmake`
```

I got the following errors:

```
-- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE 
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
CMake Error at cmake/assert.cmake:17 (message):
  

  Assertion failed: check for file existence, but filename
  (RT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND) unset.  Message: RT Library

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/tools/rt.cmake:42 (assert_file_exists)
  cmake/all.cmake:148 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
<== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
  Command 'cmake /home/znzx/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/znzx/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/znzx/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/znzx/catkin_ws/src/rostoolchain.cmake' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/znzx/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin && cmake /home/znzx/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/znzx/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/znzx/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/znzx/catkin_ws/src/rostoolchain.cmake

Command failed, exiting.
```

What is RT library? How can I do to solve the problem? Please help me.thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207608/error-while-cross-compiling-rospkg-for-arm/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-04-22

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [inspire](https://answers.ros.org/users/28884/inspire/) on 2017-01-20**:
I'v got exactly the same problem. Did you solve it in the meantime?

**Comment by [jkolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/10551/jkolb/) on 2017-08-23**:
Did you ever figure this out?  I'm hitting the same problem.

**Comment by [taogashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20902/taogashi/) on 2017-11-13**:
The same error...

**Comment by [pbeeson](https://answers.ros.org/users/695/pbeeson/) on 2018-01-20**:
I am also seeing this for certain build structures.  It seems to be a non-deterministic catkin issue not related to the CMake, but somehow related to the topology.

**Comment by [mateus-amarante](https://answers.ros.org/users/33497/mateus-amarante/) on 2018-02-01**:
Similar error here. Did someone solve the problem? I think it might be related to this pull request: https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/811.

**Comment by [antipattern](https://answers.ros.org/users/28972/antipattern/) on 2018-02-06**:
Does your rootfs provide an librt.so? If so, where?

**Comment by [mateus-amarante](https://answers.ros.org/users/33497/mateus-amarante/) on 2018-02-06**:
In my case, the librt.so is in ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/. When I add *link_directories(${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf)* (the file is there), I still get the same error.

**Comment by [antipattern](https://answers.ros.org/users/28972/antipattern/) on 2018-02-07**:
Then I am lost, I thought your toolchain might not include the multiarch dirs by itself, but if you add them manually it should work. Does crosscompiling a regular CMake project which links against librt work with your toolchain?

**Comment by [mateus-amarante](https://answers.ros.org/users/33497/mateus-amarante/) on 2018-02-09**:
It works fine with a simple CMake project. I tried to compile a catkin project again with CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE=arm-linux-gnueabihf in the toolchain file. I got the error: *"file '/mnt/bbgroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so' does not exist.  Message: RT Library"*. The lib is there.

**Comment by [antipattern](https://answers.ros.org/users/28972/antipattern/) on 2018-02-14**:
I am not sure what is happening in this case. If the library is indeed at that location, I do not see how the assertion might fail. How did you check the file exists?

**Comment by [mateus-amarante](https://answers.ros.org/users/33497/mateus-amarante/) on 2018-02-14**:
*ls /mnt/bbgroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so* outputs *librt.so*. For now, I commented the assertion step in *.../catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake*. I'm still getting errors, but I'll try a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came up with a temporary solution. My target device is a BeagleBone Black.

**1) You need to create a simple toolchain.cmake file like the following one**

```
# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# Set the target architecture
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE arm-linux-gnueabihf)

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

# where is the target environment 
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "/path/to/target-root") # no slash "/" at the end

# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# Set compiler flag
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}")
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --sysroot=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}" )
```

**2) Setup your catkin profile. Let's suppose you want to create a profile called "cross" and the toolchain.cmake file is located in src folder.**

```
catkin config --profile cross --extend /path/to/target-root/opt/ros/kinetic
catkin config --profile cross --cmake-args  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`pwd`/src/toolchain.cmake
```

It's also good to set an specific location for "build", "devel" and "install" folders.

**3) In the CMakeLists.txt of your project, place the following code before you link your targets to catkin_LIBRARIES:**

```
if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING) 
    set(fixed_catkin_libraries)
    foreach (dir ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
        foreach(root_path ${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH})
            if(dir MATCHES "^${root_path}/") # assume CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH has no "/" at the end
                list(APPEND fixed_catkin_libraries ${dir})
            else()
                list(APPEND fixed_catkin_libraries "${root_path}${dir}")
            endif()
        endforeach()
    endforeach()
    set(catkin_LIBRARIES ${fixed_catkin_libraries})
endif()
```

**4) Compile your project. If you get errors, try running `touch src/toolchain.cmake`

**References:**

[1] https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling

[2] https://github.com/AutoModelCar/catkin_ws_user

[3] https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/811

---

Originally posted by [mateus-amarante](https://answers.ros.org/users/33497/mateus-amarante/) with karma: 26 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1